# datatable cuts columnsize

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a huge csv-File that I want to upload into a db2-table. Only problem is, that it cuts the column so that I don't even get half of the columns into the datatable. I know that I can add the columns manually, but isn't there a way to do this in another way?

```
    static DataTable GetDataTableFromCsv(string path, string csvSelection, bool isFirstRowHeader)
    {
        string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";


        string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
        //string sql = @"SELECT " + csvSelection + " FROM [" + fileName + "];";
        string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" +  fileName  + "];";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            writeSchema(dataTable.Columns[0].ToString(), pathOnly, fileName);
            return dataTable;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the columns "manually"

```
private static List<string> getHeader(string fileName)
                {
                    string fullpath = @ImportPath + "\\" + fileName;
                    List<string> header = new List<string>();
                    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fullpath));

                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        var values = line.Split(';');

                        foreach (var spalte in values)
                        {
                            header.Add(spalte);
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                        return header;
                    }
                    return null;
                }

    static DataTable GetDataTableFromCsv(string path, bool isFirstRowHeader, string csvSelection)
            {
                string header= isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";

                string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
                List<string> headerList = getHeader(fileName);
                string sql = @"SELECT " + "*" + " FROM [" + fileName + "]";
                //string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" +  fileName  + "];";

                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + headerList + ";FMT=Delimited(;)\""))
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                    foreach (var item in headerList)
                    {
                        dataTable.Columns.Add(item);
                    }

                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    writeSchema(dataTable.Columns, pathOnly, fileName);
                    return dataTable;
                }

            }
```